# civicrm:publish on pantheon

Tags: composer, pantheon

Is there a way to run civicrm:publish manually and not via CLI?  I updated to 5.69.2 but have the error in status:

Wrong version of assets in public web directory: expected 5.69.2 but found 5.69.1.  Use the command composer civicrm:publish to resolve.

However, I'm on Pantheon and you can't run the command as it errors out due to permission issues.  I've tried terminus drush/composer commands to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it locally or in another dev environment and then all you need to do is upload the files in web/libraries/civicrm to web/libraries/civicrm on the real server.

Comment: Unfortunately the /web directory is read only on pantheon live servers.  It can only be modified by composer.

Comment: How did the files in web get there in the first place? Whatever user account did that should have write access?

Comment: Via composer.  On pantheon, when moving code changes from dev->test->live, composer runs as a part of the automation to update any changes.  It's not a user account that runs those updates.